# Pandas- How to append a transpose of dataframe to another dataframe as column headers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to add DF1 values as column in DF2

DataFrame1

[image: This DF needs to be append]

DataFrame2 (in which append operation is required)

[image: DF1 needs to be appended in this dataframe as a transpose]

Required DataFrame - DF3
[image: Final Output DataFrame]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `pd.concat` with an empty dataframe consisting only of headers. Here's a demo -

```
df1

          A         B
0 -0.820067 -0.078793
1 -0.341793 -0.301040
2 -0.122264  1.163896
3 -1.693027  0.147647
4 -1.322206  1.839631
5  0.902077  0.334976
6  0.628941 -1.252080
7  0.607116 -0.588056
8  0.564448  0.096036
9 -0.863496  0.345668

df2

  HeaderName
0        XYZ
1        ABC
2        SRT
3        FFF

pd.concat([df1, pd.DataFrame(columns=df2.HeaderName)], 1)

          A         B  XYZ  ABC  SRT  FFF
0 -0.820067 -0.078793  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1 -0.341793 -0.301040  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2 -0.122264  1.163896  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3 -1.693027  0.147647  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4 -1.322206  1.839631  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  0.902077  0.334976  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6  0.628941 -1.252080  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7  0.607116 -0.588056  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8  0.564448  0.096036  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9 -0.863496  0.345668  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @Coldspeed.

Comment: Nice to see you back : -)

Comment: @Wen Good to see you too :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df2 = df1.join(pd.DataFrame(columns=df2['HeaderName']))
```

Or [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df2 = df1.assign(**pd.Series(index=df2['HeaderName']))
```

Comment: Hello, nice to see you after a while! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

We can using `reindex`

```
df1.reindex(columns=list(df1)+df2.HeaderName.tolist())
Out[754]: 
          A         B  XYZ  ABC  SRT  FFF
0 -0.820067 -0.078793  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1 -0.341793 -0.301040  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2 -0.122264  1.163896  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3 -1.693027  0.147647  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4 -1.322206  1.839631  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  0.902077  0.334976  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6  0.628941 -1.252080  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7  0.607116 -0.588056  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8  0.564448  0.096036  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9 -0.863496  0.345668  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```